# How to find $[A_n,A_n]$

Tags: group-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How could I find 
$$
[A_n,A_n] \quad \cong \quad \langle ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \ : \ g,h \in A_n \rangle
$$

*My own thoughts*

I remembered that any element in $A_n$ can be written as a finite product of cycles of length $3$. Could I use that to write every commutator as some product of commutators of $3$-cycles? In this case, I take two of those cycles $\sigma$ and $\tau$ to see what their commutator looks like.

Whitout loss of generality $\sigma = (123)$. We are interested in a cycle $\tau$ that has one or two numbers in common with $\sigma$. If we'd make other choices, we would get $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} \tau^{-1} = e$. This gives us
$$
\tau \ \in \ \{(145),(124),(134) \}
$$
Do you think it would be smart to look at all the commutators I could that thiis way, or would you advise me to do something else.

Comment: I do not got it what you are asking is the defination ? $$H'=[H,H]=<[h_1,h_2]|h_1,h_2\in H>$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $g=(123)$ and $h=(145)$ we have $ghg^{-1}=(245)$. Therefore
$$
ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=(245)h^{-1}=(245)(154)=(124).
$$
Conclusion: If $n\ge5$, then every 3-cycle is a commutator of two 3-cycles. Do you see why? Do you see what it implies?

You need to handle $n=1,2,3,4$ separately, but they are easier cases. You remember that $G$ is abelian, iff $[G,G]=1$. Also if $G/H$ is abelian for some normal subgroup $H\unlhd G$, then $[G,G]\le H$. Also always $[G,G]\unlhd G$. All these points restrict the alternatives for $[A_n,A_n]$, when $n\le4$, to a single subgroup. Provided that you remember a certain exceptional subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: Note: Simplicity of $A_n$ for $n\ge5$ would lead to the same conclusion rather more quickly. I feel that this question should be settled without resorting to that bigger hammer.

Comment: I agree, but it is such a *nice* hammer...

Comment: @Koenraad: Is it clear how you get that ALL the 3-cycles are in $[A_n,A_n]$, if $n\ge5$?

Comment: I think I understand it. We know that 
$\sigma (a_1, \ a_2, \ a_3 ) \sigma^{-1} \ = \ (\sigma(a_1), \ \sigma(a_2), \ \sigma(a_3) )$
The permutation $\sigma$ involves three numbers. If $\sigma \notin A_n$, we can multiply by an inversion $(bc)$ such that $\sigma  (bc) \in A_n$ and still "works". Then we remember that
$x \cdot ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \cdot x^{-1} 
\ = \ 
xgx^{-1} \cdot xhx^{-1} \cdot (xgx^{-1})^{-1} \cdot (xhx^{-1})^{-1}$
Now we have shown that any $3-cycle$ can be written as a commutator if one can be written in that way, so we are done.

Comment: Well done, @Koenraad! Also notice that we really need $n\ge5$ here. To write $(124)$ as a commutator of two 3-cycles we needed the "help" of those extra numbers, $3$ and $5$. If $n<5$, then we don't have those two extra numbers, the argument fails, and actually the conclusion does not hold.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $G$ is a group then $[G, G]$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. This is because $g^{-1}[h, k]g=[g^{-1}hg, g^{-1}kg]$.

> Therefore, $[A_n, A_n]\unlhd A_n$.

(In fact, $[G, G]$ is *characteristic* in $G$, which means that $\phi([G, G])=[G,G]$ for all $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. This is proven using the same argument.)

For $n\geq 5$, what does this allow you to conclude?